# how to use guice injector in a guice provider?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, provider

I'm using guice to inject dependencies.

I have this provider:

```
public class RequestUrlRepository implements Provider<IRequestUrlRepository> {


    @Singleton
    @Override
    public IRequestUrlRepository get() {
        IRequestUrlRepository answer = null;
        if (System.getProperty("").equals(RouteOrCostRequest.cost.toString())){
            answer = new CostRequestUrlRepository(...);
        }
        else
        {
            answer = new RoutingRequestUrlRepository(...);
        }
          return answer;
    }
}
```

how can I use guice injector to fill `new CostRequestUrlRepository(...);`  and `new RoutingRequestUrlRepository(...)` when it's in a provider?

If not possible, how can I init them without manually creating all the ctor's params?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providers can accept `@Inject`-annotated constructors and fields, and Guice's built-in bindings will let you inject both `Injector` and a Provider for any key the injector can provide (e.g. `Provider<CostRequestUrlRepository>`).

```
@Singleton
public class RequestUrlRepository implements Provider<IRequestUrlRepository> {

    @Inject Provider<CostRequestUrlRepository> costRepositoryProvider;
    @Inject Provider<RoutingRequestUrlRepository> routingRepositoryProvider;
    @Inject Injector injector;

    @Override public IRequestUrlRepository get() {
        IRequestUrlRepository answer = null;
        if (System.getProperty("").equals(RouteOrCostRequest.cost.toString())){
            return costRepositoryProvider.get();
        } else {
            return routingRepositoryProvider.get();
        }

        // Alternatively:
        return injector.getInstance(Class.forName(System.getProperty("")));
    }
}
```

Note that the `@Singleton` annotation goes on the class, not the method; per the Guice mailing list "Scope annotations apply to providers as a whole, annotating the get() method with @Singleton is erroneous and ignored." ([link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-guice/8DJigwvWhBk/fJSyslepmI4J)).

Ideally, rather than injecting the entire injector, you should inject each provider; this should make it easier to see your system's dependencies, and then you're relying less on Guice and more on the general JSR330 annotations. However, if you have to instantiate an arbitrary class based on a name or Class literal in a variable, then injecting the Injector is the way to go.

Comment: I guice to init  `costRepository` and `routingRepository` to fill interface `IRequestUrlRepository`. I don't think i should write provider to each of them

Comment: For any binding to `X`, `Provider<X>`, or `@Provides X`, Guice will automatically create a Provider or call `provider.get()` automatically. There's no need to write your own Providers for the repositories.